# Computing Chern Number of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ Tautological Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, characteristic-classes

I'd like to compute the Chern number of the tautological bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^1$.  Consider $L \subset \mathbb{C}^2\times \mathbb{CP}^1$ given by 
$$
L \;\; =\;\; \left \{(w_1, w_2, [z_1, z_2]) \; | \; z_1w_2 = z_2w_1 \right \}.
$$

I want to compute $c_1(L)$ by considering splitting $\mathbb{CP}^1$ into two neighborhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ where $\mathbb{CP}^1 = U_1\cup U_2$ and $U_1\cap U_2 := C$ where $C$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.  If we then pick symplectic trivializations of $L$ with $U_1$ and $U_2$, then by computing the degree of the parameterization of $C$ we then obtain the Chern class.

Pick $U_1$ and $U_2$ to be 
\begin{eqnarray*}
U_1 & = & \{[z, 1] \; : \; |z| \leq 1\} \\
U_2 & = & \{[1,z] \; : \; |z| \leq 1\}.
\end{eqnarray*}

It's then apparent that $U_1 \cap U_2 = C = \left  \{ \left[e^{2\pi i\theta},1 \right] \; : \; 0\leq \theta < 1 \right \}$.  We can then pick parameterizations $\Phi_i: U_i \times \mathbb{C} \to L$ given by:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Phi_1\left ([z,1], w\right ) & = & (wz, w, [z,1]) \\
\Phi_2\left ([1,z], w\right ) & = & (w, wz, [1,z]).
\end{eqnarray*}

Because the Chern class is independent of the choice of trivializations we simply need to compute the degree of the transition between these mappings.  This is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left (\Phi_1^{-1}\circ \Phi_2\right )([1,z], w) & = & \Phi_1^{-1}\left (w,wz, [1,z] \right ) \\
& = & \Phi_1^{-1}\left (\frac{wz}{z}, wz, \left [ \frac{1}{z}, 1\right ] \right ) \\
& = & \left (\left [\frac{1}{z},1\right ], wz\right ) \\
& = & \left ([1,z], wz\right )
\end{eqnarray*}

Showing that $w\to wz$ in this transition.  This however implies that along the boundary of the two regions $C$, that $\theta \to e^{2\pi i \theta}$.

> The problem I see is that the degree of this map $C\to \mathbb{S}^1$ 
>   is just $1$, but I've been told that $c_1(L) = -1$.  Is there an error
>   in my computation or is there something I'm missing?  What is the
>   correct value of the Chern number?  Also, is there a straightforward
>   way to take this result and generalize this to the Chern number for
>   the tautological bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$?

Comment: I would ordinarily do $\Phi_j\circ \Phi_i^{-1}$ to get the transition function. To be picky, I would also point out that your $U_i$ aren't open subsets.

Comment: My recommendation, also, would be to keep homogeneous coordinates at the front and center of such computations. Then you can easily tell, by looking at $(z_1/z_0)^\mu$, what line bundle you have.